# row count in csv file to database Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to limit the no of rows before importing to db, how I can count the rows of csv file in the following function

```
def user_upload(request):
    template = "user_upload.html"
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template)
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        csv_file = None
    if csv_file:
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')
    if csv_file:
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
            if len(column) > 10:
                try:
                    users = User(
                        username=column[0],
                        first_name=column[1],
                        last_name=column[2],
                        email=column[3],
                        add_1=column[4],
                        add_2=column[5],
                        suburb=column[6],
                        city=column[7],
                        state=column[8],
                        postcode=column[9],
                        country=column[10],
                    )
                    users.set_password('password')
                    users.save()
                 
                except (IntegrityError, ValueError) as e:
                    return render_to_response('message.html')
        context = {}
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please select a valid file!')
        return redirect('home')
```

The data_set, row count is not giving the right figures, seeking help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate` to get the current row index, therefore the current row count.

```
def user_upload(request, max_row_count):
    template = "user_upload.html"
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template)
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        csv_file = None
    if csv_file:
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')
    if csv_file:
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)
        for row_count, column in enumerate(csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|")):
            if row_count >= max_row_count:
                break;
            
            if len(column) > 10:
                try:
                    users = User(
                        username=column[0],
                        first_name=column[1],
                        last_name=column[2],
                        email=column[3],
                        add_1=column[4],
                        add_2=column[5],
                        suburb=column[6],
                        city=column[7],
                        state=column[8],
                        postcode=column[9],
                        country=column[10],
                    )
                    users.set_password('password')
                    users.save()
                 
                except (IntegrityError, ValueError) as e:
                    return render_to_response('message.html')
        context = {}
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please select a valid file!')
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: tried to print the output of the code you suggested, giving a count of 10 for two rows of data, so it is actually printing the coulumn not the row

Comment: @Biju the code only check when to break the for loop, it doesn't not interfere the parsing of the data.  Without knowing the input and expected output, I can't really help.

Comment: your code is counting the columns instead of row

Comment: @Biju `csv.reader` does iterate through rows, am I misunderstanding something?  I found it interesting the variable is named `column` instead of `row`